# How would I change the Startup folder in Mac OS 10.4 using Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have tried:

1. Using the "bless ... -setBoot" command (using Terminal, no errors)
2. Scripting the OS 9 "Startup Disk" control panel ("You can't use that in OS X!" Error)
3. Recording while changing system settings (absolutely no result)

And I just can't get it to change.

For elaboration:

I am trying to change the boot device from OS 10.4 ("Scott's iMac G3:System") to OS 9.2 ("Scott's iMac G3:System Folder") with AppleScript automation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the shell man page, you should still be able to use "bless". I don't have 2 OS's on my machine so I can't test this, but it should look something like this...

```
on run
    do shell script "bless -mount '/Volumes/Scott\'s iMac G3' -setBoot"
end run
```

Take note of the backslash in your HD name before the apostrophe, this is important since I have enclosed the path name with single quotes.

P.S.  not sure if I should say "congrats" on being able to still run a machine on OS9 or say "might be time to upgrade"... either way..."Wow!"

Comment: I tried the "bless mount" before, but it only blessed the folder for some odd reason, and only the first time I ran the command it would boot to OS9. Also it's an actual iMac G3, hence the HD name...      P.S. Late night coding FTW (9 pm in my area)

Comment: @Scottzuz22Blacklock Can you show the entire "bless" command you used?

Comment: It was `bless -mount '/Volumes/Scott\'s iMac G3/System Folder' -setBoot` and don't worry, I don't and shouldn't upgrade, considering I am using a super powerful Windows laptop also being uninformed about the base features of Mac OS 9 and X.

Comment: @Scottzuz22Blacklock again, sorry i can't test this, but the way I read the man page, if you're going to add "System Folder" as part of your path, you need to add the `folder` flag to your `bless` command. Might be worth trying it as I wrote it.  P.S. 10 pm here ;)  [see the man page info here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/bless.8.html)

Comment: I used `folder`, but it broke OS 9. 1. It didn't load any extensions. 2. On "Restart", "No longer valid System Folder", 3. Can't change resolution 4. Text looks weird 5. Mouse sucks

Answer (score 0):

From OS X to OS 9 the parameter is `-folder9` and the path must point to the OS 9 System Folder.

```
do shell script "bless -folder9 '/Volumes/Scott\'s iMac G3/System Folder' -setBoot" password MyPassword with administrator privileges
```

From OS 9 to OS X the parameter is `folder` and the path must point to the CoreServices folder in the system library.

```
do shell script "bless -folder '/Volumes/Scott\'s iMac G3/System/Library/CoreServices' -setBoot" password MyPassword with administrator privileges
```

I recommend to rename the computer to avoid the hassle escaping the apostrophe.

Comment: I did, also I can't test it right now... I took apart my G3, and it will no longer turn on. I did not take anything out. I'm guessing one of the screws were ground and 99% of the screws, I did not put back in. I'll test it as soon as possible.